# jQuery Mobile listview refresh is not applying inset look and feel

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'm pulling JSON data fromlocalstorage and using grep to filter out the items needed based on a selected ID.  I then take the filtered set and convert it ti "LI" items then append them to a UL container.  The UL container has the data-inset attribute set to yes.  When I apply listview("refresh") to the "UL" the inset look and feel is not applied (rounded corners on first and last items.

Here's my code:

```
    var categoryId = 1;                 
    var data = JSON.parse(... data from localstorage...);

    //FILTER OUT DATA FOR THE SELECTED CATEGORY
    data = $.grep(data, function(el, i) 
    { 
        if (el.CategoryId == categoryId)
            return el;
    });

    //BUILD LI ELEMENTS FROM FILTERED LIST
    var categoryListItems = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, item) 
    {
        categoryListItems.push('<li data-category-id="' + item.CategoryId + '" data-id="' + item.ListId + '">' + item.ListName + '</li>');
    });

    $('ul#CategoryList li').remove();
    $('ul#CategoryList').append(categoryListItems.join('')).listview("refresh");
```

Looking at the resulting HTML, the CSS classes "ui-corner-top" and "ui-corner-bottom" are not getting applied after the refresh.  These are the classes that round the corners on the first and last li element for the inset look and feel.

Any ideas as to why these classes are not getting applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this

```
$('ul#CategoryList').append(categoryListItems.join('')).listview("refresh", true);
```

Comment: The additional true parameter keeps the rounding effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after listview refresh

`$("#pageid").trigger("create");//pageid is the id of the page which has the listview.`

This will force a rebuild of the page with all jquery mobile styles getting reapplied.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't make a difference.  I put the $("#pageid").trigger("create"); right after the listview refresh call.

Comment: You have to replace pageid in the code snippet with whatever id you are using for the page(data-role='page').For eg:if the id was categorypage,you should use $("#categorypage").trigger("create");